# How to create an Observable<Type> from an Observable<List<Type>>

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

If I have an `Observable` of a `List` of `Letter`s

```
public Observable<List<Letter>> getAToZList() {
        return Observable.create(
                new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Letter>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Letter>> subscriber) {
                        List<Letter> aToZLetters = getLetters();
                        subscriber.onNext(aToZLetters);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

How do I then create an `Observable` that observes a single `Letter` and emits one for each in the `List`?

```
public Observable<Letter> getAToZ() {
        return Observable.create(
                     getAToZList().something() ??
        );
    }
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flatMapIterable`. For example:

```
observable.flatMapIterable(l -> l).subscribe()
```